# C++ std::locale::global - using in a DLL affects calling program?

Tags: c++, dll, locale, std, setlocale

I have an interesting problem with C++ locales.  We have a DLL which takes text string parameters and does some hardware interfacing.  The details of that aren't too important; the main point is that it's a DLL and not a statically-linked library.

We found that there was a problem for European users, where they use commas as decimal symbols.  The DLL was still using the default C locale with decimal points, so it didn't interpret them correctly.  Adding the call `std::locale::global(std::locale(""));` in the DLL picked up the current locale settings and made this work correctly.

I've now found that this causes separate problems with programs using the DLL though.  A calling program (a separate EXE which dynamically loads the DLL) now prints numbers with thousand separators, picked up from the current locale.  I can prove that this is the reason by changing the locale settings and by testing with old and new DLLs.  But the calling program is unchanged - only the DLL loads the locale.  The calling program never had a locale set so was still using the default C locale.

Is this expected behaviour?  I expected each separately-compiled executable to have its own std::locale::global settings - I did not expect DLLs to reference (and change) a program-wide setting in the calling program.  Am I correct here, or is this a bug in the C++ runtime?

I've looked at the appropriate reference pages [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/setlocale) [and here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/global) but it doesn't seem clear to me that it should work this way.

(We're using the MSVC 2013 runtime, by the way.  Yes I know it's old - we just haven't had a strong reason to change yet.)

Comment: Not a CRT bug, locale is a global variable of the C runtime.  A DLL *can* have its own copy of the CRT but that is often a recipe for trouble.  Global CRT state matters.

Comment: @HansPassant Global for this program then - or global for every program on the PC using the C runtime?

Comment: Not per program, but per *process*.

Comment: This is a good example of why global variables in C++ can be such a pain. And why you should not use them in your own code (libraries)